# Run-time error 424 Object Required

Tags: excel, vba

I want to find the date I type into an input box in a selected row. I am getting the

> Run-time error 91 Object variable or With block variable not Set

error at the `f.Select` line. Please advise what I did wrong. Thanks much.

`Sub Add_Batch_Macro()`
    `Dim mRange  As Range`
    `Dim New_Batch_Date As Date`
    `Dim f As Variant`
    `Range("A1").Select`
    `ActiveCell.Rows("1:5").EntireRow.Select`
    `Selection.Copy`
    `Selection.End(xlDown).Select`
    `ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select`
    `ActiveSheet.Paste`
    `wsDate_Header_Row = ActiveCell.Row`
    `var_Batch_Qty = InputBox("Batch Quantity is:", "Enter the Batch Quantity:", "")`
    `ActiveCell.Offset(4, 3).Select`
    `Selection.Value = var_Batch_Qty`
    `ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 1).Select`
    `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[2]C4-R[-1]C"`
    `Application.CutCopyMode = False`
    `New_Batch_Date = InputBox("Use Format: mmddyyyy", "Enter the New Batch Date:", "")`
    `Application.Rows(wsDate_Header_Row).Select`
    `Set mRange = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(wsDate_Header_Row, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(wsDate_Header_Row, 20))`
    `Set f = mRange.Find(What:=New_Batch_Date, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)`
    `f.Select`
    `End Sub`

Comment: Range requires row and column. `wsDate_Header_Row` only holds row.

Comment: The column would change based on the date I need to find in the range (an entire row). If I understand your advice correctly, I'm not sure how specifying a column is what I want. Maybe there is another way to find something based on an input variable that I am missing?

Comment: You have the right idea. Like Bob said below, you can use a variable named `column_number` and set that to the column you need.

Answer (score 1):

Edited per OP comment on other answer.

```
Dim mRange  As Range
Dim New_Batch_Date As Date
Dim f As Variant

wsDate_Header_Row = ActiveCell.Row
New_Batch_Date = InputBox("Use Format: mm-dd-yyyy", "Enter the New Batch Date:", "")

Set mRange = Range(Cells(wsDate_Header_Row, 1), Cells(wsDate_Header_Row, 20))

Set f = mRange.Find(What:=New_Batch_Date, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

f.Select
```

Comment: Now I get Run-time error 91 Object variable or With block variable not Set at the f.Select. I copied/pasted your code and declarations just in case, but the error persists.

Comment: That's my fault. Try `Set mRange = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(wsDate_Header_Row, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(wsDate_Header_Row, 20))`

Comment: I copied this new code line into my code, removed the old code it replaces but I still get the same error at the f.Select statement.

Comment: Uh works fine for me :/ Is this the entirety of your code? Did `f` actually find something?

Comment: My full code is over the posting limit by 400 characters. Is there another way I can display it all? `wsDate_Header_Row` is correct at 6 (the entire row is highlighted); variable `New_Batch_Date` is correct as entered at 4/1/2016; `var_Batch_Qty` is correct as entered but still it bombs on f.Select.

Comment: You can always edit OP but did `f` find something? Also, shouldn't date be `04/01/2016`? You're not hopping between sheets right?

Comment: I edited the OP heading and included the full code above. I did not edit the title of the OP. When I hover over `f.Select` it shows `wsDate_Header_Row = 6`The sixth row is the correct row. I receive the same result if I enter the date with and without leading zeroes and using slashes or hyphens. I stay within the same worksheet which is called "Lot Info" Tyvm for sticking with this :)

Comment: Sigh. As predicted `f` is empty. I don't know what you want to do. You're better off rephrasing your question to explain what you want to do because your code leaves a lot to be desired :/ Edit: I am leaving soon and won't be back till Monday.

Comment: Gave you one for your effort here bro.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to create a range object variable, you have to set it to an range object. When you use `Set mRange = wsDate_Header_Row` you are trying to set it to a row number not an object. You should use something like `Set mRange = Cells(wsDate_Header_Row, column_number_or_letter)` where column_number_or_letter points to your target column.

Comment: There are around 20+ columns that can contain the date I need to find in a single row, so I will update 10 to 20. I received a Run-time error 91 Object variable or With block variable not Set at mRange.Find.